# Can not start activity from command line in Android 13

Tags: android, adb, intentfilter, android-13

I cannot open activity from the terminal via the command below,

```
adb shell am start -n com.mypackage/com.mypackage.MyActivity -d --es myvariable1 myvalue1 --es myvariable2 myvalue2 -d
```

On Android 13 it returns:

> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
> cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] dat= pkg=username
> cmp=com.mypackage/.MyActivity } Error type 3 Error:
> Activity class {com.mypackage/com.mypackage.MyActivity} does not
> exist.

It works on Android 12 and lower.

Couldn't find any information about that except https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-all#intents

When I match the Intent filter as mentioned in the link

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d myscheme://myhost/myprefix -n com.mypackage/com.mypackage.MyActivity
```

opens but I need to open activty with my parameters without myscheme://myhost/myprefix and View intent

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is the activity marked as `exported=true`?

Comment: Yes it is @Robert

Comment: Same issue, with another app . No way to resolve!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add a separate intent filter to launch:
https://automationchronicles.com/error-when-opening-chrome-on-android-13-via-adb/

e.g.

```
<activity
        android:name=".mypackage.MyActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      </intent-filter>

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="myhost"
            android:scheme="myscheme" />

      </intent-filter>
```